# Where is the infinite loop?

Tags: java, infinite-loop

Hello this is my first message in overflow(Sorry if the question is too long) and im also junior at java and english.

I've recently read a mind game. Question was something like this:
There is four women,and their names: kirmizi - yesil -sari -mavi
(these are colour names in Turkish) Each woman wears a skirt in one these colours. For example;

mavi woman wears sari skirt

but there are two rules:

None of the women's skirt colour should not be same as their name

also the length of their names and skirts cant be equal. For example, mavi woman can't wear sari skirt. But she can wear kirmizi and yesil.

Can you find each woman's skirt colour?

And I've tried to solve it but it goes into infinite loop

Colour=renk
name=isim             in turkish:)

Edit: I've just found out new clues. Miss kirmizi and sari can't wear mavi and yesil skirts. Also their skirts are different colour. I can write the answer if you want but I believe this is a good problem for beginners like me :)

```
package ana;

class Ana {

   static boolean birtobir=false;
   static boolean ikitoiki=false;
   static boolean uctouc=false;
   static boolean dorttodort=false;

   String renk;
   String isim;
   public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] isimler={"bir","iki","uc","dort"};
        String[] renkler={"kirmizi","sari","yesil","mavi"};

        Ana bir = new Ana();
        bir.isim = "kirmizi";
        bir.renk="kirmizi";

        Ana iki = new Ana();
        iki.isim = "sari";
        iki.renk="sari";

        Ana uc = new Ana();
        uc.isim = "yesil";
        uc.renk="yesil";

        Ana dort = new Ana();
        dort.isim = "mavi";
        dort.renk="mavi";

        while ( birtobir=true && bir.renk.matches(bir.isim))
               while( ikitoiki=true && iki.renk.matches(iki.isim) )
                      while( uctouc=true && uc.renk.matches(uc.isim) )
                              while( dorttodort=true && dort.renk.matches(dort.isim)) {

                                    for (int a=0;a<renkler.length;a++) {
                                        bir.renk=renkler[a];

                                        if(bir.renk.length()==bir.isim.length()) {
                                            boolean birtobir=true;
                                        }

                                        for (int b=0;b<renkler.length;b++) {
                                            iki.renk=renkler[b];

                                            if(iki.renk.length()==iki.isim.length()) {
                                                boolean ikitoiki=true;
                                            }

                                            for (int c=0;c<renkler.length;c++) {
                                                uc.renk=renkler[c];

                                                if(uc.renk.length()==uc.isim.length()) {
                                                boolean uctouc=true;

                                                for (int d=0;d<renkler.length;d++) {
                                                     dort.renk=renkler[d];

                                                }
                                                if(dort.renk.length()==dort.isim.length()){
                                                     boolean dorttodort=true;
                                                }

                                            }
                                        }   
                                    }
                               }                        
     } 


    System.out.println(bir.isim+"="+bir.renk);
    System.out.println(iki.isim+"="+iki.renk);
    System.out.println(uc.isim+"="+uc.renk);
    System.out.println(dort.isim+"="+dort.renk);


    }
}
```

Comment: You should start by indenting your code correctly, so it isn't so difficult for others read. Also, rather than offering a translation guide, just do a search and replace.

Comment: did you try to use a debugger and see where the inifite loop is? and to which variable/s is/are constant or out of range when you are in the infinite loop?

Comment: Hi.  Please could you explain the meaning of the vars `birtobir`, `ikitoiki`, `uctouc` and `dorttodort`?  Also, adding comments to your code describing what is going on will not only help others analyse it, but might also help your own understanding of it, too.

Comment: Add a System.out.println in your innermost loop so that you see what's going on there -- or use a debugger.

Comment: At first glance it seems like the main method is just going to return without going through any loops; you define `birtobir=false` and your first loop is `while ( birtobir=true && bir.renk.matches(bir.isim))
`.

Comment: @daiscog - that's pretty easy, it's like a "mapping": `birtobir` is *bir-to-bir* and so on.

Comment: yes daiscog is right .they are 1-2-3-4 in turkish but i dont think they are too much important.Anyway Thx for answer.It was very fast.Thanks again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's just a guess, but in here:

```
while ( birtobir=true && bir.renk.matches(bir.isim))
               while( ikitoiki=true && iki.renk.matches(iki.isim) )
                      while( uctouc=true && uc.renk.matches(uc.isim) )
                              while( dorttodort=true && dort.renk.matches(dort.isim)){
```

most likely you want: `birtobir==true && .. ikitoiki==true && ... uctouc==true && ... dorttodort==true` [use **operator==** instead of the **operator=**]

`birtobir=true` sets birtobir to be true, while `birtobir==true` checks if the variable is true.

more details on [operators in java](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html)

If it is not a bug, and you actually want to set the vaeriable - it's a bad styling and you should [refactor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_refactoring) your code.

**EDIT:** 
One more thing I can notice:

```
   if(bir.renk.length()==bir.isim.length()){
            boolean birtobir=true;
        }
```

In here, you create a **new variable** named birtobir, and set it to true. This variable is NOT the variable checked [or supposed to be checked] in the `while` loop. I assume you actually want to set the class member to true. To do so, replace `boolean birtobir=true;` with `birtobir=true;`

Comment: Well spotted.  Furthermore, when checking a boolean there's no need to use `==` at all:  `if (birtobir && ...` is nicer than `if (birtobir==true && ...`

Answer (score 0):

A single `=` assigns a value to a variable, while `==` checks for equality. This means you should change the conditions in your while loop to check for equality instead of assigning a value.

I.E.
`while ( birtobir=true && bir.renk.matches(bir.isim))` is effectively the same as `while (bir.renk.matches(bir.isim))`. 
It should therefore be changed into `while ( birtobir==true && bir.renk.matches(bir.isim))`

edit: what amit says..

Answer (score 0):

Here's my rendition. If I understand correctly you want to print all the valid combinations?

```
public class Colours
{
  private static String[] names = new String[]{"kirmizi","yesil", "sari", "mavi"};
  private static String[] colors = new String[]{"kirmizi","yesil", "sari", "mavi"};


  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++)
    {
      for (int j = 0; j < colors.length; j++)
      {
        if(allowed(names[i], colors[j])) {
          System.out.println(names[i] + " may wear " + colors[j]);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  private static boolean allowed(String name, String color) {
    return (!name.equals(color)) && (name.length() != color.length());
  }
}
```

Comment: No,No not ALL the valid combinations.i need to find which woman is wearing which skirt?But your code is very good and simple it helped me a lot thx

Answer (score 0):

Can't tell for sure what's going on, but you seem to have to many cycles.

I'd try to start with a naive but simple algorithm:

```
for (person in persons) {
    for (color in skirtColors) {
        if (person.name != color && person.name.lenght != color.lenght) {
            person.skirtColor = color;
        } else {
            person.skirtColor = "";
        }
    }

    if (allPersonsHaveSkirts(persons)) {
        // a more complete check should be done
        // to make sure they all have different colored skirts
        printSolution();
    }
}
```

By using 2 simple, finite `for` loops, you guarantee that no infinite loops happen.